# How to create a read-only server role on SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, sql-server-2012

I am granting the "View any database" permission when creating a new server role, but realized this permission only allows the user to view the system databases.

I am trying to create a server role that is read-only and can read any database.

Is there a way to create a user-defined server role to read user databases? Or do I have to do this through user mapping per user?

Comment: This is best asked on dba.stackechange.com

Comment: What about the default role `db_datareader` ?

Comment: M. Ali, that is at the database level. I am trying to see if there is a way to do it through the server level so I don't have to manually add users as db_datareader to each database.

Answer (score 0):

So, no is the answer, you can't assign database level permissions to server level roles, you can't even add a server role to a database role, which I find really frustrating as I've tried to do the same thing as you.

The way I ended up doing this was not by using a server role at all, I did the following:

- Created an AD group for each server that I wanted read only access for
- Created a login on the server for the group
- Assigned the login to the db_datareader role on the model database
- Assigned the login to the db_datareader role on all the pre-existing databases
- Added my windows users into the AD group

This way, you can simply assign (or train your servicedesk folks to assign) users who need read only access to all databases on a server to the AD group, plus, as the role is set in the model database, they will have access to all newly created databases on the server too.